# dart says "non-nullable variable must be initialized before use", even after assigning with if, else block

Tags: flutter, dart, scope

Trying to do this. Would be neat if I could avoid implementing the full code in both condition.

```
  String dateToday;
  //if time is past 6pm, get next date:
  if (fetchTime.hour > 18){
    final dateToday = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(fetchTime.add(Duration(days: 1)));
  }
  else{
    final dateToday = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(fetchTime);
  }

  final Map<String, String> params = {
      'district_id': '$districtId',
      'date': dateToday                //ERROR HERE  <------
  }
```

ERROR:

> The non-nullable local variable 'dateToday' must be assigned before it
> can be used. Try giving it an initializer expression, or ensure that
> it's assigned on every execution path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using wrong. You have to set value to already defined variable. In other words, don't use a final keyword in this case.

```
  String dateToday;   //if time is past 6pm, get next date:   
  if (fetchTime.hour > 18){
    dateToday = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(fetchTime.add(Duration(days: 1)));   
  } else{
    dateToday = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(fetchTime);   
  }

  final Map<String, String> params = {
      'district_id': '$districtId',
      'date': dateToday    }
```

Update from author's comment, added by OP:

final keyword should be used when declaring a variable.
Since the dateToday was already declared, using final inside the scope creates a new local variable dateToday and the outer dateToday remains unassigned.

Comment: You are right. Removing the final did it. It was my understanding that final should be used when the value to a variable was being fixed at that point.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why final shouldn't be used here? Since the value is not going to change afterwards, why not use it.  Flutter  likes having final wherever possible.

Comment: Accourding to Dart documents, final keyword is used to hardcode the values of the variable and it cannot be altered in future, neither any kind of operations performed on these variables can alter its value (state). Also, if you want to set value into any variable, you have to declare that variable first. You already declared your variable before if condition. It means you must not use final keyword in this case @VaisakMohan

Answer (score 1):

when you use final in there you are declaring new variable in both if and else scopes which type is automatically is dynamic. therefore your initial dateToday variable will not be assigned. when you are trying to read it from outside of the if and else statement you are refering to your String dateToday variable which is not assigned. Therefore dart complain that you did not assign variable before use.

Try using this

```
 late String dateToday;
      //if time is past 6pm, get next date:
      if (fetchTime.hour > 18){
        dateToday = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(fetchTime.add(Duration(days: 1)));
      }
      else{
        dateToday = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(fetchTime);
      }
    
      final Map<String, String> params = {
          'district_id': '$districtId',
          'date': dateToday                //ERROR HERE  <------
      }
```

Comment: This worked. Even without the late keyword.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why final shouldn't be used here? Since the value is not going to change afterwards, why not use it.

Comment: when you use final in there you are  declaring new variable in both if and else scopes which type is automatically is dynamic. therefore your initial dateToday variable will not be assigned. when you are trying to read it from outside of the if and else statement you are refering to your String dateToday variable which is not assigned. Therefore dart complain that you did not assign variable before use.